# Does the existence of an indirect proof imply the existence of a direct proof?

Tags: proof-writing, philosophy

So direct proofs are often considered more informative than indirect ones. This got me thinking, and as far as I believe this question has no practical implication - does the existence of an indirect proof imply the existence of a direct proof, for any given problem in any given field?
I know this might just be a yes or no answer, but is there an explanation for it that even a layman can understand?

Comment: To my knowledge, in combinatorics, it is often the case that if an unintuitive proof by induction is found for an identity, researchers will still search for an intuitive combinatorial proof (showing the two sides count the same thing differently). From this, I conclude that finding intuitive proofs of already known facts can be valuable and non-trivial.

Comment: How do you define "direct proof" vs "indirect proof"? Perhaps the [Well-ordering theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem) is an example of something that can only be proved indirectly. In order to prove it for infinite sets, you have to make infinitely many arbitrary choices, which cannot be done explicitly. Instead we assume by making it an axiom that given any collection $\scr A$ of non-empty sets, there is a function $f : \scr A \to \bigcup A$ such that for all $A \in \mathscr A, f(A) \in A$.